# What is a proven text classification method beyond tfidf+svm?

Tags: text-classification

I'm doing text classification and Tfidf+LinearSVM does pretty well.

Do you know a reference which demonstrates another technique that is shown to do better?

I'm specifically looking for *evidence* that another specific model does better, because there are a lot of opinions what should do better, but most of it doesn't, and I'd like to start with something promising based on real evidence.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with LSTM then try transformers.